Помогите со сравнением айди юзера и айди юзера из БД SQLite
Я сделал БДшку, в которую по команде я могу добавить айди юзера и это айди туда сохраняется. Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать айди юзера из БДшки и сравнить его с айди юзера из чата, он не проверяет его, айди в БД есть, а проверка говорит, что всё в порядке.
Код из db.py
import sqlite3
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE white(adduser_id INT)")

def get_users(adduser_id):
    db = sqlite3.connect('data.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT adduser_id FROM white WHERE adduser_id=?", (adduser_id, ))
    rows = cursor.fetchone()
    print(rows)
    return rows

Код проверки из main.py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['checkwhite'])
async def close_bot(message: types.Message):
    if db.get_users_exist(message.chat.id) == True:
        if message.chat.id == db.get_users(message.chat.id):
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Добро пожаловать')
            print(db.get_users(message.chat.id))
        else:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='у тебя нету прав')
            print(db.get_users(message.chat.id))

Upd: на принты не обращайте внимание, я их добавил чтоб понимать, что видит БД

«принты» — ну тогда логичный вопрос: что выводит print(rows) и что выводит print(message.chat.id) и играли вы в игру «найди три отличия»?

ну так забейте мой код и посмотрите что выводит print(rows) и print(message.chat.id), разница и есть и я пытаюсь от этой разницы избавиться

Если я забью ваш код, я получу ошибку NameError: name 'dp' is not defined, потому что вы не предоставили [mcve] и потому что лишнего телеграм-бота у меня всё равно нет. А пытаться угадывать, что у вас там выводится и от чего вы там пытаетесь избавиться, здесь никто не будет

Да в общем-то и фраза «он не проверяет его» максимально мутная: кто «он», кого «его», что значит «не проверяет», что происходит вместо «проверки», какое конкретное ожидаемое поведение, какое конкретно фактическое поведение?

понял, бывает. Весь код не могу вам показать, но его работой я доволен

А весь и не надо, надо [mcve] (возможно даже без телеграм-бота, потому что телеграм в общем-то не имеет прямого отношения к вашей проблеме)

Нашёл ответ на свою проблему, вместо:
rows = cursor.fetchone()
print(rows)
return rows

я поставил:
if cursor.fetchone() is None:
    return False
else:
    return True`

и всё заработало как следует.

Ну, в таком виде выражение message.chat.id == db.get_users(message.chat.id) всегда будет выдавать False, так что вы явно сделали что-то ещё
